# .NET MVC Dump Route Table

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

Is there an easy way to dump all routes for a .NET MVC application? I'm thinking something similiar to how rail's `rake routes` works.

http://archives.ryandaigle.com/articles/2007/7/2/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-use-rake-to-list-your-routes

Comment: might be helpful
http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/13/routedebugger-2.aspx/

http://mvcroutevisualizer.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Its actually pretty difficult to do a **reliable** one depending on your use case because routes are usually very dynamic. Attribute-based routing would make the task much easier but I will assume you are not using that. I have found this [article which uses reflection](http://www.visheshpatel.com/aspnet/map-all-routes-in-aspnet-mvc-using-reflectioin), but I have not tried it myself. Also, its a simplistic approach, which won't cover many edge cases.

There are tools such as [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com) that allow you to view most of your routes and debug them (including AJAX!) but even that will have trouble with routes that don't follow the conventions in the RouteConfig, or that have context masks which make them route via other controllers, etc. To my knowledge they don't have an API for analyzing or